# 5/12V voltage TTL selector

Tags: mosfet, diodes, opto-isolator, voltage-source

I want to **select** an output of 5 or 12 V with an isolated digital output control signal (Vcc 3.3V in the picture, **0** selects 5V, **1** selects 12V). Right now I have something like this:
[image: wrong version]

Corrected version:

[image: 5/12V selection circuit]

This works for **one** output, but when I replicate the circuit (sharing the 5 and 12 V between them), if I select, say, 5 V for one output and 12V for the rest, the 5V turn into 7V.

Should I add a diode somewhere to control backward current? Could the circuit be improved in some way? Maybe there is a better alternative? Mechanical relays are not an option and I'm *far* from being an expert.

Many thanks!

Comment: Q1 and Q2 have their drain and source the wrong way round. Look at the (bulk)diodes in the MOSFETs, this way you will always have 12 V at the output.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've updated the image! In the actual circuit were correct.

Comment: Assuming you can't live with a 1 diode drop, you will need some sequencing circuitry to avoid momentarily putting +12 on the 5V circuit (break before make).

Comment: What do you mean by 1 diode drop exactly?

Comment: PLEASE do not change the image if there are already comments and especially answers relating to it- you just screw up all the previous comments and answers. Add an image to the previous one. If you don't have enough rep leave a link and someone will add it for you.

Comment: One diode drop is around 0.5 to 1V depending on current and diode type, so if you used common 1N5819 Schottky diodes you might have as little as 4.4V from a 5.00V input at 1A out.

Comment: Regarding your changed diagram, look carefully at the body diode in Q1 when output is +5V. Also as the optocoupler is switching there may be a brief period of time when the 5V and 12V supplies are shorted together and anything connected to the +5 (including the regulator) might go poof.

Comment: Sorry, I have uploaded again the wrong version. I understand the problem you say, I'll try @Master's proposal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. OA1 provides interlock between the 5V and 12V supplies (at low slew rate) while D1/R3 and D2/R4 provide break-before-make switching when edges are sharp.

M1 is a P-channel MOSFET conventionally connected. M2 is an N-channel MOSFET connected in 'reverse' so that the body diode does not normally conduct. During switching the body diode will briefly conduct during the dead time when both MOSFETS are off, and output voltage will drop to ~4.3V with a load.

R2 is a pullup to allow M1 to switch off completely. If M1 has insufficient Vgs rating for transients on the 12V supply you can simply connect a zener from gate to source without any additional parts. M2 should be a logic-level MOSFET- it must be fully on with 7V Vgs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6IZkF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the 5V supply appears before or without the 12V supply it will backfeed the 12V supply with 2 diode drops (so the 12V supply will go to ~3.6V)

Comment: Pretty complex, I'll try Master's circuit first. It may take some time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand how your circuit is expected to work.

You have to use 2 P channel MOSFETs, both having their Sources to the power supply side and Drains connected to the load. Then use a kind of inverter to drive the gate of any one of them:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnto5Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Diode D1 is a low forward voltage drop Schottky diode. NXP has several suitable diodes with 3 A current rating and voltage drop about 0.3 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1nOF9.png)</sup>

This circuit is simple. It s only disadvantage is: when +5 V is selected, it makes +4.8 .. +4.7 V depending on its load. However, this is within 10% typical tolerance for power supply voltage. D1 must be a good Schottky diode!

In case this tolerance is not acceptable, I suggest looking for suitable ICs called "zero forward drop diodes" or even "power switchers". The first kind of IC is in fact a pair of MOSFETs in power line with a built-in logic that makes them work as a diode with a forward voltage drop of 10 mV or about.

The "power switch IC" makes the complete functionality you need (switching between two alternative power lines) on one chip. However, 12 V is a high voltage for them, you need to look for a suitable part carefully.

Comment: Won't work- body diode of M3 conducts when output is +12 and puts 11.3V on the 5V PS.

Comment: Add Schottky diode in series with M3

Comment: It would be better to use an N-channel logic-level MOSFET backward, IMHO (no diode drop on the 5V) but there's still the (possible) problem of momentarily connecting +5 to +12.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean to add the schottky in the D of M3?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, thank you for fixes! Yes, N-channel MOSFET gives still lower voltage drop, you are right. But it makes the circuit a bit more complex and, you are right again, we have to add some short delays to prevent momentary connection of +12 V to +5 V. Guess this connection may burn MOSFETs under certain conditions...

Comment: I changed schematics a little: the diode D1 was added.

Comment: However, it seems we can do much simpler circuit. See new schematics.

Comment: Thanks, Master, the simpler circuit seems to work in a simulation, but I get 10.135V instead of 12V in the output. Maybe I should choose a different MOSFET model (I tried 2N7002CK). For the diode I tried 1N5820RLG and the output says 5V.

Comment: Sorry, M1 in a simpler circuit must be P channel MOSFET! The voltage drop in your simulation comes from Gate to Source voltage to make MOSFET conducting.

Comment: Let me check, I'll tell if it worked (it may take weeks). Thanks again!